# How to display Maintenance page for my application deployed in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, maintenance-plan

Considering I have multiple applications deployed in Tomcat. I had planned for maintenance for a particular application. So I want to block the request for that particular application and redirect to a static page, informing the users it is in a planned maintenance.

To achieve this with tomcat configuration, is it possible?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution, that I haven't seen else where, relies on the use of the [RewriteValve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html), so it's dedicated to SO users. You will need a Tomcat restart to activate it.

Add the valve in your Host definition in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` :

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
```

Edit or (more likely) create `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config` file with this content :

```
# for a missing webapp which would be named fewbars
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} ^/fewbars/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance/index.html [R,NC]

# for a deployed webapp named fewbars
RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_PATH} /fewbars
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance/index.html [R,NC]
```

As commented, the behaviour depends on the webapp status : if the war file and the directory have been removed then you need to match on the REQUEST_PATH. On the contrary, to hide an application whose war and directories are still there it will be matched by CONTEXT_PATH.

You understand that you need a `/maintenance/index.html` file in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps directory`